# Input Box Error Handling

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble handling the error associated with a input box "Cancel" click. Or in otherwords, it returns an error within the sub if the value of the input is null. I have tried looking around and still can't seem to get it quite right. Here is my attempt:

```
Private Sub bttnSavingsExpected_Click()
Dim expected() As String
Dim nPeriods As Integer
Dim counter As Integer
Dim savings As Single

With ActiveSheet.Range("A13")
    nPeriods = Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End With

ReDim expected(1 To nPeriods)

counter = 1

For counter = 1 To nPeriods
    expected(counter) = Range("A13").Offset(counter, 0).Value
Next

TryAgain:
On Error GoTo ErrH
counter = 1
For counter = 1 To nPeriods
    savings = InputBox("How much savings do you expect from " & expected(counter) & "?", "Savings?", Range("A13").Offset(counter, 1).Value)
    If savings = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Range("A13").Offset(counter, 1).Value = savings
    End If
Next

Exit Sub
ErrH:
MsgBox "Please enter value. If the default value is desired then please click 'OK'.", vbOKOnly, "Do Not Click Cancel"
GoTo TryAgain

End Sub
```

With this attempt, the MsgBox is displayed the first click whether there is a input or not and even if I click "Ok". The second try of clicking "OK" or "Cancel" leads to being kicked back to the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got `Dim savings As Single` and `If savings = "" Then`.  Thats always going to error

Try using `Dim savings As Variant`

Comment: Well that was an easy fix! I am new to this so I forget how easily variables can mess you up quick. Just an additional note to anyone who looks to this for framework, the `TryAgain` `On Error GoTo` and `ErrH` portions don't apply to the needs I expressed. The If statement does the trick.

Thanks by the way!

Comment: Also once a `variant` if the cross or cancel on the input box is pressed a `FALSE` results. Be sure to catch these.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the variable for the Inbox is set at "", then test the value for False.  Much easier than anything else I have seen:

```
Sub WolfPackURL_input()
Dim TheURL As String
Dim SaveURL As Hyperlink
Set savedURL = Sheets("Data").Range("I1")

TheURL = ""
TheURL = Application.InputBox("Input the Sign-Up URL", "Wolfpack Weekly Players URL", "http://something", 1)

If TheURL = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Activate
Sheets("Data").Range("I1").Hyperlinks.Delete
Sheets("Data").Range("I1").ClearContents
Sheets("Data").Range("I1").Clear

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Sheets("Data").Range("I1"), Address:=TheURL, ScreenTip:="Open file", TextToDisplay:=TheURL

End Sub
```